# I'm creating a website with the Django framework and I have a problem

Tags: python, django, django-templates

path('accounts/login/', auth_view.LoginView.as_view(template_name='app/login.html', authentication_form=LoginForm), name='login'),

path('logout/', auth_view.LogoutView.as_view(next_page='login'), name='logout'),

when i want to use logout function i have set in my urls.py as above and also i have linked it well in my base.html like this
href="{% 'logout' url %}"

and in the terminal there is a message Method not allowed(GET): /logout/ Method Not Allowed:/logout/

but after I tried the logout page it didn't work please help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting in Django [4.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/releases/4.1/#features-deprecated-in-4-1), logging out via GET request is no longer supported. It only accepts POST request. Do this instead:

```py
<form method="post" action="{% url 'logout' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Logout"/>
</form>
```